# How to check whether a small portion of audio (let's say a particular Audio Ad) is present in the complete Audio log file (All Audio Advertisements)?

Tags: python, audio, extract

I am new to the Audio analysis. What I want is let's a brand ad is played during breaks of a TV commercial which contains many ads of other brands.

I want to check how many times my brand ad is played during the commercial break and at what time interval it was played.

I have both audio files.

Can anyone please help me on this using python?